# How to add one object to other all objects in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs

I have a `json` file called by `fetch` request that looks like this:

```
[
{
    "type": "1",
    "flight": {
        "_id": {
            "value": "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",
            "provider": {
                "provider_id": "2",
                "dmnid": "3984-5cb59eca68f75451df7f828f"
            }
        },
        "info": {
            "departureinformation": {
                "routeshow": {
                    "dateinfo": [
                        {
                            "startdeparture": [
                                {
                                    "_id": 10648.0,
                                    "sstring": "1398-02-25",
                                    "mstring": "2019-05-15",
                                    "weekday": "4"
                                }
                            ],
                            "enddeparture": [
                                {
                                    "_id": 10648.0,
                                    "sstring": "1398-02-25",
                                    "mstring": "2019-05-15",
                                    "weekday": "4"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "total": 21361210.0,
        "totalCom": 21361210.0,
        "commissioncost": 0.0
    }
},
{
    "type": "2",
    "id": {
        "hotelId": "105254",
        "provider": {
            "provider_id": "23",
            "dmnid": 3984.0
        }
    },
    "hotelinfo": {
        "name": "CVK Park Bosphorus Hotel",
        "hotelsearch": {
            "realname": "CVK Park Bosphorus Hotel",
            "hotelid": 0.0,
            "hotelimage": "",
            "star": 5.0
        }
    }
},
{
    "type": "2",
    "id": {
        "hotelId": "105256",
        "provider": {
            "provider_id": "23",
            "dmnid": 3984.0
        }
    },
    "hotelinfo": {
        "name": "CVK  Hotel",
        "hotelsearch": {
            "realname": "CVK  Hotel",
            "hotelid": 0.0,
            "hotelimage": "",
            "star": 5.0
        }
    }
},
{
    "type": "2",
    "id": {
        "hotelId": "105252",
        "provider": {
            "provider_id": "23",
            "dmnid": 3984.0
        }
    },
    "hotelinfo": {
        "name": "Bosphorus Hotel",
        "hotelsearch": {
            "realname": "Bosphorus Hotel",
            "hotelid": 0.0,
            "hotelimage": "",
            "star": 5.0
        }
    }
}
]
```

As you can see every object of `json` has a field called `type`. For example if there were 100 objects , 99 objects would have `type`field with value `2` and 1 object would have `type` field with value `1`. I want the object by `type=1` will be added to all objects by `type=2`.

```
 class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        data: [],
        library: null,
        perPage: 20,
        currentPage: 1,
        maxPage: null,

    }
}
componentDidMount() {
    fetch('/json.bc', {
        method: 'get',
    })
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(text => {
            let Maindata = JSON.parse(text.replace(/\'/g, '"'))
            this.setState(state => ({
                ...state,
                data: Maindata
            }), () => {
                this.reorganiseLibrary()
            })
        }).catch(error => console.error(error))

}

reorganiseLibrary = () => {
    const { perPage, data } = this.state;
    let library = data;
    library = _.chunk(library, perPage);
    this.setState({
        library,
        currentPage: 1,
        maxPage: library.length === 0 ? 1 : library.length
    })
}



// Previous Page
previousPage = event => {
    this.setState({
        currentPage: this.state.currentPage - 1
    })
}
// Next Page 
nextPage = event => {
    this.setState({
        currentPage: this.state.currentPage + 1
    })
}

// handle per page
handlePerPage = (evt) =>
    this.setState({
        perPage: evt.target.value
    }, () => this.reorganiseLibrary());

// handle render of library
renderLibrary = () => {
    const { library, currentPage } = this.state;
    if (!library || (library && library.length === 0)) {
        return <div>NOResult</div>
    }
    return library[currentPage - 1].map((item, i) => (
        <div className="Wrapper">{this.rendermain(item, i)}</div>
    ))
}



render() {
    const { library, currentPage, perPage, maxPage } = this.state;
    return (
        <div>
            {this.renderLibrary()}
            <ul id="page-numbers">
                <li className="nexprevPage">
                    {currentPage !== 1 && (
                        <button onClick={this.previousPage}><span className="fa-backward"></span></button>
                    )}
                </li>
                <li className="controlsPage activeCnt">{this.state.currentPage}</li>
                <li className="restControls">...</li>
                <li className="controlsPage">{this.state.maxPage}</li>
                <li className="nexprevPage">
                    {(currentPage < maxPage) && (
                        <button onClick={this.nextPage}><span className="fa-forward"></span></button>
                    )}
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}
rendermain(element, i) {
    let type = element.type
    let saveProduct = ""
    let productToBeAdded = ""
    if (type == '2') {
        saveProduct = <div className="box-hotel">{element.hotelinfo.name}</div>
    }
    if (type == '1') {
        productToBeAdded = <div className="box-flight"><img src={element.flight.info.departureinformation.ticketinfooo.showstartairline} width="100" height="40" alt="" /> </div>
    }

    let final = saveProduct.push(productToBeAdded)
    console.log(final)
    return final
}
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('Result'))
```

I tried to use `push` but there was this error : `saveProduct.push is not a function`

Comment: FIrst find object with type 1 and add it to object which type 2. Like this : https://repl.it/repls/FloweryVagueApplications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get the object with `"type": "1"`

```
const type1 = data.find(({ type }) => type === '1');
```

Then loop through `data` and if the id is `"1"` return it, else merge `type1` with the current object

```
const mergedData = data.map(obj => obj.type === '1' ? obj : { ...type1, ...obj });
```

Change `componentDidMount` to this

```
componentDidMount() {
  fetch('/json.bc')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      const type1 = data.find(({ type }) => type === '1');
      const mergedData = data.map(obj => obj.type === '1' ? obj : { ...type1, ...obj });

      this.setState(state => ({
        ...state,
        data: mergedData,
      }), this.reorganiseLibrary);
    }).catch(console.error);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Asaf Aviv for your answer. Sorry but could you please show it in my code?I got what you mean nearly but I do not know to how to use it in my code.

Comment: Updated the answer check it and let me know

Comment: Thanks @Asaf Aviv, but it looks that the objects would not be merged. when I write  `console.log(mergedData)` it shows me the default json without merging type =1 by type=2 .and when I write : `return library[currentPage - 1].map((item, i) => (
         {item.hotelinfo.name}
        ))` in return , there would be this error : `item.hotelinfo is undefined`